# Is there a quiz block plugin for dashboard?

Tags: moodle

In my site dashboard, I want to post interesting questions for everyone on the site and the answers by the students should not be public. The Latest Announcement block gives the option to create a forum for the dashboard and post questions as discussions. Even though there is a reply private option, it's optional.

I feel a quiz is better suited to this purpose. Is it possible to show quiz questions in a block plugin like how the forum is shown as a block plugin: latest announcement?

Or is there a way to force students to privately reply to the latest announcement posts?

I searched Moodle Plugins repo for block plugins to display quizzes but did not get any.

I went to the permissions of the Site Announcement forum, removed the student from the Reply to posts capability, and added the student role to the Reply Privately to Posts capability. Just as I thought the reply button in the post was not visible anymore.

I followed https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=144080 and tried to embed Quiz in an HTML post but after I clicked post, the Iframe code was deleted from the post's description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add quiz in frontpage and the quiz url can be pasted at html block. Students can ne navigate from the block or from the quiz itself.